# Change of base matrix and invert-ability

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say you want to express the vectors $u_1, u_2, u_3$ in the basis $\mathbb{B_v}$

$u_1 = a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + a_3v_3$

$u_2 = b_1v_1 + b_2v_2 + b_3v_3$

$u_3 = c_1v_1 + c_2v_2 + c_3v_3$

If $w_{\mathbb{B_u}} = (\alpha. \beta, \gamma)$ i.e $w_{\mathbb{B_u}} = \alpha u_1 + \beta u_2 + \gamma u_3$

we can write $w_{\mathbb{B_u}}$ as

$$\left( \begin{array}{3} \alpha a_1+ \beta b_1 + \gamma c_1 = 0 \\ \alpha a_2+ \beta b_2 + \gamma c_3 = 0 \\ \alpha a_3 + \beta b_3 + \gamma c_3 = 0 \end{array}\right ) = \left( \begin{array}{3} a_1, b_1, c_1 \\ a_2, b_2, c_3\\ a_3, b_3, c_3\end{array}\right ) \left( \begin{array}{3} \alpha \\ \beta \\ \gamma \end{array}\right )$$

This means that the matrix: $$ A =\left( \begin{array}{3} a_1, b_1, c_1 \\ a_2, b_2, c_3\\ a_3, b_3, c_3\end{array}\right )$$

This is the change of basis matrix from the base $\mathbb{B_u}$ to $\mathbb{B_v}$.

**Now my textbook claims that this matrix is:** *"Obviously invertible since the columns are linearly independent, this is due to the fact that the coordinates come from coordinate vectors from linearly independent vectors.*

**Now this last part is what I have trouble understanding.**

**For example:**

That the coordinates in the columns in themselves are linearly independent is not hard to understand since they were expressed in a base $\mathbb{B_u}$, like: $u_1 = a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + a_3v_3$.

But that the columns in $A$ are linearly independent from each other must be harder to assert?

As far as I understand the coordinates for $\left( a_1, a_2, a_3 \right )$ could be the exact same as *(or a multiple of)* $\left( b_1, b_2, b_3 \right )$ and hence the vectors $u_1$ and $u_2$ would be linearly dependent?

Wouldn't this make the base change matrix $A$ not invertible?

Obviously there is something here that I have missed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if $u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_n$ are linearly independent, then their coordinate vectors with respect to a different basis $\mathcal{B}$ are still linearly independent. I'll denote these coordinate vectors as $[u_i]_{\mathcal{B}}$.

**Proof:** Recall that $[au + bv]_{\mathcal{B}} = a[u]_{\mathcal{B}} + b[v]_{\mathcal{B}}$ for $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and vectors $u, v$. Thus, if $c_1 [u_1]_{\mathcal{B}} + c_2 [u_2]_{\mathcal{B}} + \ldots + c_n [u_n]_{\mathcal{B}} = 0$, then we have $[c_1u_1 + c_2u_2 + \ldots + c_nu_n]_{\mathcal{B}} = 0$. Generally, if $[u]_{\mathcal{B}} = 0$, this means that $u = 0 v_1 + 0 v_2 + \ldots 0 v_n = 0$. Thus, we have shown that $c_1 u_1 + \ldots + c_n u_n = 0$. Of course, since the $u_i$ are linearly independent, this happens exactly when $c_1 = c_2 = \ldots = c_n = 0$. This proves that the $[u_i]_{\mathcal{B}}$ are linearly independent, as claimed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @AlexG. I am trying to look at your proof now, but a question pops up in my head, how can we be sure that the vectors $u_1, u_2, u_3$ in my example are linearly independent?

Comment: Aren't we assuming that the $u_i$ are a basis?

Comment: Yes we probably are, that might be why I was confused about this...

Answer (score 1):

This is an instance of a more general theorem.

If $V$ is a $n$-dimensional vector space over field $K$, then $V$ is isomorphic to $K^n$. In other words, there's a bijective linear map $$
  \mathfrak{C} \,: V \to K^n \text{.}
$$
In fact, there are *many* such maps $\mathfrak{C}$ - for each pair of bases $(v_i)$ of $V$ and $(b_i)$ of $K^n$, requiring that $\mathfrak{C}(v_i) = b_i$ defines a different such map. **And, as for all *invertible* linear maps, the *image* of a linearly independent set of vectors is again linearly independent!**

In particular, if $(b_i)$ is the *canonical* basis of $K^n$, i.e. if $$
  b_i = (\underbrace{0,\ldots,0}_{\text{$i-1$ times}},1,0,\ldots,0) \in K^n
$$
and if $B = (v_i)$ is a basis of $V$ then $$
  \mathfrak{C}_B \,:\, V \to K^n \,:\, v_i \mapsto b_i
$$
is the *coordinatization map* corresponding to the basis $B$ of $B$.

So if we're talking about the coordinates $(c_i)$ of some vector $x \in V$ with respect to a basis $B$ of $V$, then we're really talking about the vector $c \in K^n$, where $c = \mathfrak{C}_B(x)$. So it follows, from the bold sentence above, that the image of a linearly independent set of vectors in $V$ under $\mathfrak{C}_B$ is a linearly independent set of vectors in $K^n$.

Comment: Thank your for your answer! I will study this, It might be a bit over my level, but trying never hurts :)

Comment: @LukasArvidsson I can promise that if you understand this, then a lot of things will suddenly become much clearer. If "field" confuses you, then just replace $K$ by $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. What this is really all about is the *meaning* of coordinates, and the *reason* we can take an *arbitrary* finite-dimensional vector space and *treat* vectors as $n$-tuples of coordinates.

Comment: Thank you! Great to know, then I will study this thoroughly!